# Horizontally and vertically center div in the middle of page with header and footer stuck to top and bottom of page

Tags: css, html, alignment

I'm trying to make a page where I have a fixed height header and footer. The header is at the top of the screen (100% width) and the footer is at the bottom (100% width). I want to center a div with variable height content in the space between the header and footer. In the below jsfiddle, it works if the content is shorter than the space, but if the content gets too long, it goes past the footer, and over the header. It also doesn't work at all in IE (surprise, surprise).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VrfAU/4/

**Edit:** I've made some images to try and make this more clear.

**Small content**

[image: The content box is centered horizontally and vertically.]

**Large Content**

[image: The content box is longer than the gap between the header and footer, so it stretches the page, keeping the footer at the bottom.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up starting over and trying a different approach. The working solution is found in the new jsfiddle below. The idea was to separate the header and footer from the content area so that they would sit on top and bottom. Then it became much easier to center the content area in the space between those (with some hacks for older versions of IE).

http://jsfiddle.net/UYpnC/5/

Comment: Worked first time for me in Chrome but initially did not work in Firefox or Explorer. However the Fiddle worked perfectly in all three browsers. After doing some checking it turned out Firefox and Explorer required all floats in the header to be cleared. Clearing them with `overflow: hidden` solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
.main { min-height: 500px }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VrfAU/8/

Comment: That doesn't solve any of the issues. The blue box is completely removed from the screen in your example, and the main point is to have it centered on the screen.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VrfAU/9/

what you need to do is a set width on a div, then you want to apply 'margin: 0 auto' to center it

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't use up the full screen. The footer should be all the way at the bottom of the screen (no matter the height of the blue box), and then the blue box should be in the middle.

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/layout.css

What you're looking for is called a "sticky footer" if this one doesn't work for you, try search around google for some sticky footer information.

Comment: Right, but that combined with the way you implemented centering of the blue box wouldn't center the blue box since you centered it with 50px margins, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I used the css property z-index, which controls the stack order to fix this:
I also used position: fixed to fix the header and footer:

I put

```
        #header {
background: black;
width: 100%;
height: 66px;
position:fixed;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 20;}


.main_wrap {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: -88px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
#footer {
background: black;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
font-size: 85%;
color: #d0d6e0;
margin-top: -22px;
position: fixed;}
```

Comment: That just hides the content behind the header.

Comment: I don't want the header and footer to float either. Sorry if my wording was confusing, I updated it.

Comment: Did you remember to save your changes? The jsfiddle you linked shows no header and has the footer going through the middle of the blue box.

Comment: Ok, let me clarify, you want a fixed header and footer? with the content underneath? Or do you want a header and footer at the top and bottom with the content pushing the footer down?

Comment: No, I want the header at the top, the footer at the bottom (neither being fixed), and the blue box to be centered in the gap between them (both horizontally and vertically). If the blue box is too tall, then yes it should push the footer down. I hope that makes a little more sense.