# Horizontally and vertically center div in the middle of page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a page layout like the following 
[Horizontally and vertically center div in the middle of page with header and footer stuck to top and bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155702/horizontally-and-vertically-center-div-in-the-middle-of-page-with-header-and-foo/8673689#8673689)

This works great in all browsers except ie6 and ie7.

Can any one help me how to fix this? I am a server side developer and new to front end. I did some searching but could not found the solution.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: can you post some code please?

Comment: `display: table-cell;` does not work in IE7 and below, which in the answer to the SO question you have linked to is being used to vertically align the div

Comment: Hi, You can have look at this link http://jsfiddle.net/UYpnC/5 for code.

Answer (score 5):

Centering vertically with CSS can be a pain. Check out [Dead Centre](http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html). It requires an extra container 'horizon' to know where the vertical center is, and unfortunately you must know the dimensions of the content you want centered so that you can offset it.

Goes something like this...

```css
body {
  margin: 0px
}

#horizon {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: visible;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block
}

#content {
  margin-left: -125px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 70px;
  visibility: visible
}
```

```html
<body>
     <div id="horizon">
          <div id="content">
               content you want centered
          </div>
     </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your replies. Here is the code which is mentioned in the above post
http://jsfiddle.net/UYpnC/5/

I have looked at dead center so if there is header and footer centered div goes over the header and the footer because of the absolute position.

Here table-cell I cannot use because it doesn't support older browsers like ie 7/6.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Bachi, as the other have mentioned, support for `display: table-cell` is spotty. If you use the Dead Centre method above, combined with `position: fixed` for the header and footer ('top' for header, 'bottom' for footer') would that work?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.centered {
  background-color: red;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
```

Answer (score 0):

This no longer works well on Chrome 38. Try loading the dead center site above and resizing the browser - see the distortion in the text.